# Define operator! for shared_ptr<A>

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have a problem with defining `operator !` for my class. I use `shared_ptr<A>` objects and I would like to use `!` on them.

```
shared_ptr<a> b;
bool result = !b; // using my operator, not !shared_ptr
```

I tried few times but I'm getting ambiguous error.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, and what you want the operator to do?

Comment: is `shared_ptr<a> b;` just for illustration here or do you really intend to invoke that operator with a default constructed `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
shared_ptr b; 
bool result = !*b;
```

Comment: Causes UB if b is null

Comment: Yep you can always drive a Ferrari into a lake

Comment: @Jellyboy My solution to that is not to drive a Ferrari. You seem to imply that yours is to drive near lakes. 

Comment: I like lakes very much, yes. In my country all lakes and beaches and bodies of water are public. But I never had a Ferrari, sadly. I have an Audi RS5 though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. You need to dereference the pointer first.

```cpp
bool result = b and !(*b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` doesn't have an `operator!` defined, but you can compare the pointer it is holding, eg:

```cpp
shared_ptr<a> b;
bool result = !b.get();
```

Alternatively, it does have an `operator bool` defined:

```cpp
shared_ptr<a> b;
bool result = !(bool)b; // or: !static_cast<bool>(b)
```

Alternatively, it also has `operator==` defined for `nullptr`:

```cpp
shared_ptr<a> b;
bool result = (b == nullptr);
```

Comment: `!b` works, there is no need for any of what you showed https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T1adPP8aE

Comment: What OP is trying to do is to call `operator!` of the underlying object, not the shared_ptr

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili nothing in what the OP said suggests that.